Flutter: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel, null, null) during Firebase Initialization on iOS
I'm encountering an issue with Firebase initialization in my Flutter app specifically on iOS. The app throws the following error when trying to run await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform):
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:210:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:66:31)
<asynchronous suspension>

What I've Tried:
Upgraded all Firebase packages to the latest version.
Ran flutter clean, flutter pub get, and flutter pub upgrade.
Tested with older versions of Firebase packages.
Deleted Podfile.lock, ran pod install and pod update.
Tested on a physical iOS device (iPhone SE 3rd generation).
This issue has persisted for 3 days, and I haven't found a working solution. The Android version works fine; the problem is specific to iOS.
My flutter sdk is
Flutter 3.22.3 •
Tools • Dart 3.4.4 • DevTools 2.34.3
cloud_firestore: ^5.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.4
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^11.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^12.1.3
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  intl: ^0.19.0
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  pdf: ^3.11.1
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  photo_view: ^0.15.0
  printing: ^5.13.1
  provider: ^6.1.2
  signature: ^5.5.0
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid_export: ^26.2.9
  syncfusion_flutter_xlsio: ^26.2.9
  universal_html: ^2.2.4
  universal_io: ^2.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  share_plus: ^10.0.0

Any help or insight into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I don't have idea to fix issue
